# How to create Three-Line Listview Items?

Tags: android, listview, material-design

I have three-line items on my Listview ( [like this one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pxeGV.png) ), but I want to change it like [this other](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hKvwR.png). What I want to do is to have this "--" divider between the subheader (the black one) and the complementary text (the grayish one), and I want the complementary text to be in the second and third line.

This is the code I'm using for my items (doesn't include avatar's code)

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtNombrePDV"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="La bendición"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryText"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:lines="1"
        android:scrollHorizontally="true"
        android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
        android:textSize="@dimen/list_primary_text" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtNombreMunicipio"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Stack Overflow"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryText"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:lines="1"
        android:scrollHorizontally="true"
        android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
        android:textSize="@dimen/list_secondary_text"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtDireccion"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit"
        android:textColor="@color/colorSecondaryText"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:lines="1"
        android:scrollHorizontally="true"
        android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
        android:textSize="@dimen/list_secondary_text"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your layout should go like this.

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvTitle"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textSize="18dp"
            android:textColor="@color/subHead"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_below="@+id/tvTitle"
            android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Subhead"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:id="@+id/subHeader"
            android:textColor="@color/colorText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

and java code should look like below.

```
 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    int color = ContextCompat.getColor(this,R.color.subHead);
    String title = "Brunch this weekend?";
    String name = "Ali Connors";
    String message = "I will be in weekends so get set ready. Will meet you yesterday";
    String subTitle = name+" - "+message;
    SpannableString spannableString = new SpannableString(subTitle);
    spannableString.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(color),0,name.length(), Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    TextView subTitleTextView = findViewById(R.id.subHeader);
    TextView titleTextView = findViewById(R.id.tvTitle);
    subTitleTextView.setText(spannableString);
    titleTextView.setText(title);
}
```

colors

```
  <color name="subHead">#252525</color>
    <color name="colorText">#797979</color>
```

Answer (score 0):

Combine the text for Subheader & Complimentary text,use Spannable String to set the colors to respective text.
[Refer this spannable string example](http://androidcocktail.blogspot.in/2014/03/android-spannablestring-example.html) for better understanding